# Long words appear on new line rather using break-word to break the word

Tags: html, css

When writing articles I sometimes need to use long strings with no spaces and instead of the word breaking and wrapping, these words are being put in their own line. This leaves a big gap of whitespace in the preceeding sentence.

You can see an example of this here in the "How CryptoRoger Encrypts a Victim's Files" section:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/new-ransomware-called-cryptoroger-that-appends-crptrgr-to-encrypted-files/

I also added an example in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s5u53vmq/

My CSS is currently set to the following so that words don't overflow the div and I was hoping break:

```
.articleBody p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Is there anything else I should be using so that these long words break rather than moving to the next line?

Comment: It's working, just not in an obvious way. Extend the `uTox address` by 10 characters and you'll see it working. It's not obvious that the browser will move it to a new line to fit as much of the word in as possible before it breaks. But does make some sense.

Comment: Thx. Would love to figure out a way to remove that large whitespace for stylistic reasons. In a perfect world, the long word would start right after uTox address and just break so it flows better.

Comment: I added a fiddle showing the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/s5u53vmq/

Comment: updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're willing to use extra markup I think you might be at the will of the browsers and how they handle long, run-on text.

This solution also requires extra markup but is a lot more dynamic in where the word will break. While solutions like `<wbr>` and `<shy>` work, they require you to dictate exact places to break the word. Which, in some situations is what's desired. My solution requires a single tag wrapped around the word you want to break and will break it dynamically.

```css
.inline-word-wrap {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<p>
  When the ransomware is done encrypting your files it will open the ransom 
  note called&nbsp;<strong>!Where_are_my_files!.html</strong>&nbsp;as shown 
  above. This ransom note will contain instructions stating developer at 
  the uTox address <span class="inline-word-wrap">F12CCE864152DA1421CE717710EC61A8BE2EC74A712051447BAD56D1A473194BE7FF86942D3E.</span>
</p>
```

Your updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5u53vmq/3/).

Comment: Thanks. Wish there was a way to do this 100% dynamically with CSS, but this solution at least lets me wrap a long word and let the browser decide how it wraps. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice for a pure CSS solution. If there is one I have not seen it. Not sure if it's coming down the pipeline or not. I'm assuming the current implementation is an attempt to get the run-on to not break in the first place, which then makes sense as why it drops to the next line and then breaks if needed. I think the visual pattern they're going for the `[space][word][space]`. Maybe someone with more insight on the hows and whys of this behavior can drop us a line.

Answer (score 1):

You can just mark breakpoints for the browser in your long strings using:

- `&shy;` breaks with a dash
- `&#x200b;` breaks invisible

Comment: Thanks for the info as I didn't know about this tag. This works, but looking for something that can be automated with CSS rather than me having to implement these tags.

Answer (score 1):

The `<shy>` tag ("soft hyphen") allows you to mark positions in words where a break between lines (including a hyphen) is allowed. That way the words won't be broken at any position that's close to the end of the line, but only at positions where you allow it.

An abstract Example: `abcdef<shy>ghijkl<shy>mnopq<shy>rstuvwxyz` will be written as `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` if it fits into one line o be broken (with a hyphen)  at the `<shy>` tag which is closest to the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks for the info as I didn't know about this tag. This works, but looking for something that can be automated with CSS rather than me having to implement these tags.

Answer (score 0):

The `<wbr>` tag, introduced in HTML5 and AFAIK supported everywhere signifies a place when breaking a chain of characters is allowed. It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info as I didn't know about this tag. This works, but looking for something that can be automated with CSS rather than me having to implement these tags.

Answer (score 0):

using css -

```
.articleBody p{
  /* These are technically the same, but use both */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  /* This is the dangerous one in WebKit, as it breaks things wherever */
  word-break: break-all;
  /* Instead use this non-standard one: */
  word-break: break-word;

  /* Adds a hyphen where the word breaks, if supported (No Blink) */
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

Another solution. Preventing Overflow with Ellipsis -

```
.articleBody p{
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```